# Sort multiple query results in a single query

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a select statement returning 5 columns:

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from table1;

col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 9     A    B   C    D
 8     E    F   G    H
```

I have another select statement from table2 which returns col1 alone;

```
col1
8
9
```

Based on the two select queries, is there a way to write a single select query to return the result as:

```
 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
    8     E    F   G    H 
    9     A    B   C    D
```

ie. basically sort the output of I query based on col1 from II query. (this is in Mysql)

PS:II table column1 is used to for sorting & that is coming from table 2. Table2's col1 is not static, its changing for every user action & based on a call i will get col1 of table 2 & need to sort with table1's output.

Comment: Update the question to demonstrate how table 2 is incorporated, because the example is pretty clear otherwise that table 2 is not used.

Comment: You have screen1 where you can move around grids on a page, grid1,grid2,grid3 etc. their sorting order is stored in table2, where as tabel1 returns information on grids which must be displayed on what order grids are stored in table2.

Comment: Is this two completely seperate tables? Is Col1 in table1 and table2 exactly the same?

Comment: Yes. For say if table1 has col1 has 10,11,12 with other columns & table2 has the same in 12,11,10 then i need to display the output as 12 11 10 for table 1 with other data in this order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work, you `seriously` need a `sort` column on table2.  Just having the IDs in table2 is **not enough**.  You can have the records 7,8,9, then delete 8 and add it back.  But **no**, that doesn't `order` it as 7,9,8.  Maybe temporarily if there is no primary key on the table, but when the table gets large, even that "implicit" order is lost.

So, assuming you have such a sort column

```
Table2
Sort, Col1
1, 9
2, 8
```

Your query becomes

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.col1 = b.col1
ORDER BY b.sort ASC
```

**If you still want** to rely on MySQL undocumented features or the way it currently works, then you can try this.

```
# test tables
create table table1 (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);
insert table1 select 8, 1,2;  # in this order
insert table1 select 9, 3,4;

create table table2 (col1 int);
insert table2 select 9;  # in this order
insert table2 select 8;

# select
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.col1 = b.col1

----output----
col1  col2  col3
9     3     4
8     1     2
```

This works at least for small tables, only because size(table2) < size(table1) so it collects in that order, preserving the filesort on table2.col1.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ORDER BY:

```
  SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 
    FROM table1
ORDER BY col1
```

By default, ORDER BY is ASC.

```
  SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 
    FROM table1
ORDER BY col1 DESC
```

...will put 9 from col1 as the first record returned.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Sorry II table column1 is used to for sorting & that is coming from table 2. Table2's col1 is not static, its changing for every user action & based on a call i will get col1 of table 2 & need to sort with table1's output.

Comment: II table's col1 value will be dynamic, for one login it will be 8,9, next login it will have IDs 11,10 as sort order. So if the I query returns 10,11 order then i need to return the output as 11,10.

Comment: Sharpeye500: That's the opposite of your original example, if the col1 has to be DESCending sort based on the col1 values.  It can't be both.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I added comments to my question, see that sounds as a valid question.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I am trying to give you an example, sort order can be anything, just i need to return the way its stored.

Comment: Sharpeye500: I get that sort values can be anything, the orientation can't -- you need some way to know if it should be ASC or DESC, outside of the value themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the relationship is between t1.col1 and t2.col2. Probably looking for something like this though:

```
SELECT t2.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4, t1.col5
  FROM table2 t2
 INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
 ORDER BY t2.col1 ASC
```